# glBindBuffer attempts to read/write to protected memory

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a Texture class, that at some point needs to clear its pixel data and load new texture  pixel data from a file. It loads and displays its first texture just fine. But when it comes to changing its displayed texture, it simply displays its old pixel data with the new images dimensions.

I'm trying to clear the old pixel data from OpenGL's buffers using a call to `glBindBuffers`. I first delete the old texture name in this function `reloadTexture()`.

```
void Texture::reloadTexture(string filename)
{
    //first and foremost clear the image and buffer vectors back down to nothing so we can start afresh 
    buffer.clear();
    image.clear();
    w = 0;
    h = 0;
    //also delete the texture name we were using before
    glDeleteTextures(1, &textureID[0]);

    const char* fnPtr = filename.c_str(); //our image loader accepts a ptr to a char, not a string
    //printf(fnPtr);

    lodepng::load_file(buffer, fnPtr);//load the file into a buffer

    unsigned error = lodepng::decode(image,w,h,buffer);//lodepng's decode function will load the pixel data into image vector from the buffer
    //display any errors with the texture
    if(error)
    {
        cout << "\ndecoder error " << error << ": " << lodepng_error_text(error) <<endl;
    }
    //execute the code that'll throw exceptions to do with the images size
    checkPOT(w);
    checkPOT(h);



    //loop through and //printf our pixel data
    /*for(GLuint i = 0; i<image.size(); i+=4)
    {
    //printf("\n%i,%i,%i,%i,", image.at(i),image.at(i+1),image.at(i+2),image.at(i+3));

    }*/

    ////printf("\nImage size is %i", image.size());

    //image now contains our pixeldata. All ready for  to do its thing

    //let's get this texture up in the video memoryOpenGL
    texGLSecondaryInit();

    Draw_From_Corner = CENTER;
}
```

Then in the function `texGLSecondaryInit()`, I attempt to clear any residual pixel data and load new data from another file.

```
void Texture::texGLSecondaryInit()
{

    glGenTextures(1, &textureID[0]);
    ////printf("\ntextureID = %u", textureID[0]);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID[0]);//evrything we're about to do is about this texture
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    //glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER,0);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8,w,h,0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &image[0]);

    //we COULD free the image vectors memory right about now.
    image.clear();
}
```

Now in order to try and clear the buffer to make sure that it's the new pixel data that texture draws from, I was advised to use `glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER,0);` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729088/glgentextures-works-but-returns-the-same-texture-name-every-single-time/17729265?noredirect=1#comment25888460_17729265) question. However for doing this, I get unhandled exception errors for access violation.

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Spritey.exe Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

I also noticed that this is a System error. Meaning that it could be something to do with the fact that the `Texture` class isn't managed code. However, I make the compiler aware of this using

```
#pragma managed(off,push)
```

Does anybody know why I can't safely call `glBindBuffer` here? Or an alternative that'll let me purge whatever texture data openGL has?

Comment: `#pragma managed` is not C++. Perhaps you should add appropriate tag and mention it, because C++ tag is about ISO C++ code.

Comment: Are you sure you have got the function pointer for glBindBuffer() correctly?

Comment: @derhass I'm confused as to your meaning. Can I not just call glBindBuffer as I would any other function? Or is there a longer process to calling it involving function pointers.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I'm aware that `pragma managed` is cli, however, the last time I tagged a question both `C++` AND `C++/CLI`, I got chewed-out by a much more experienced member. Telling me that "C++ ISNT C++/CLI". (Something i was completely aware of, but I was using both managed and unmanaged code). The Texture class i refer to in this question IS unmanaged c++, so I *think* that the c++ tag is relevant. I only briefly mention about `pragma managed` at the end. Even though in it's largest scope, this is from a `c++/cli` project.

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean: well, it depends a bit on your platform. But the correct way to call any of the non-ancient GL functions on almost any platform is using the extension mechanism. On Windows, for example, only GL1.1 is part of the Windows API, calling everything else requires you to query the function pointers first.

Comment: i thought it was simply a matter of including glew.h and linking to the lib in visual studios dependencies paths. Aparently not so. Do you know how I "query" the function pointers. Or a place where i can find out. Because there's nothing about it in the openGL docs.